# why is ajax giving late result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to get value from ajax and following jquery using in script for ajax:

```
$("#disc-num").keyup(function(){
    var discountCode = $("#disc-num").val();
    $("#jps-coupon-code").val(discountCode);
    var ticketId = <?php echo $_GET['ticketId'] ?>;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/includes/registration-ajax.php',
        data: {myDiscCode:discountCode, myId:ticketId},
        success: function(more){
            $("#myDiscount").val(more);
        }
    });
});
```

and my ajax file(registration-ajax.php) is below:

```
if(isset($_POST['myDiscCode'])){
 $discCode = $_POST['myDiscCode'];  
 $tickId = $_POST['myId'];
 $discQuery = "SELECT * FROM jps_coupon WHERE coupon_code='$discCode' AND ticket_id='$tickId'";
 $Query = mysqli_query($con, $discQuery);
 while($my=mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){
     $cDiscount = $my['coupon_discount'];
 }
 echo $cDiscount;
}
```

and my HTML file is below:

```
<div class="input-group add-on" id="discount-div">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="disc-num" style="border-top-right-radius:0 !important;border-bottom-right-radius:0 !important;">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="apply">Apply</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Above code sometime works and sometime not, problem is ajax is taking time to give result in success.
so please check my ajax and tell me why success:function responding late.

Comment: If the code works sometimes and not others it would indicate a server-side issue - assuming both requests contain the same data. Check the console for errors with the request when it fails and also any server logs you have. How long is the response taking to come back? It's possibly a timeout issue.

Comment: Open developer console (F12) and go to the "Network" tab. Click on the "Apply" button and see what happens with the request.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen it is showing two rows with same value - name (registration-ajax.php), status - 200, Type - xhr, initiator - jquery.min.js:4 , size - 346B, Time 3.01s

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i have check console for errors but it is not showing anything.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen i have noticed that when status is showing pending, my ajax not works and if status is 200 then it works perfectly. so what should i do my status not show pending.